# Display results of unknown SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a requirement that I'd like to know if it is possible. I have visualforce page which will display the results of a SOQL query, however the SOQL query is dynamic and could be a query on Custom Objects or Standard Obejcts. I'm currently hard coding a SOQL query into the controller class whilst trying to figure out how it will work. I intend to display the results of the SOQL query in a pageBlockTable or dataTable in the Apex.

Is this possible in Salesforce, if so could anyone give me an example of how it would work both in Visualforce and Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about "dynamic references" (also called "dynamic bindings"). A good starting point: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_standard.htm

Basically if you have `String fieldName = 'AccountNumber';`, later in Visualforce you can refer to it directly:

`<apex:outputField value="{!a.AccountNumber}">` or dynamically:

`<apex:outputField value="{!a[fieldName]}">`.

This is similar to having `a.AccountNumber` or `a.get('AccountNumber')` in Apex. Check out for example [getting Value of a field by its Name in apex salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114586/getting-value-of-a-field-by-its-name-in-apex-salesforce) if you've never seen it.

---

You'll have to be careful around them because if your base object won't be account it will fail (for example there's no `Contact.AccountNumber` field). The example above deals with Accounts only but it'd be a good intro anyway.

Once you familiarize yourself with the basic idea you can explore world of [fieldsets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) - predefined groups of fields that should come together - you can use them both for displaying and querying data, basically they're more powerful than hardcoded list of strings with the field names (like in first link) but still same idea.

At least you'll know now what keywords to look for ;)

Comment: That's great, thanks eyescream. I understand how that would work when I know the object that I'm querying but in this case the object being queried is also dynamic. For example, my controller is a customReportController through which I will have multiple reports on the page all referencing different objects, the SOQL to be run is stored in a field on the custom report object. Considering this, is this still possible?

Comment: Should be, anything can be downcast to sObject and so - query results can be `List<sObject>` too... The get/put methods belong to base sObject class too, not to "Account" etc. I vaguely recall it needed bit more care when actual data stored was not String but for example date (mostly formatting issues). But generally dynamic output works fine, dynamic inputfield might be sometimes tricky. Maybe just experiment with it and update your question with some code if you'll hit any obstacles?

Comment: Thanks for your help eyescream.