# Adding rows in visualforce page in PageBlocktable dynamically

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am creating a dummy visualforce page whose code is

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages id="message" />
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrap1}" var="item" id="hello">
    <apex:column headerValue="String" value="{! item.x}"></apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Action"><apex:commandButton value="{!if(item.i == size-1,'Add','Delete')}" onclick="AddOrDelete({! item.i});" rerender="message"></apex:commandButton></apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:actionRegion >
     <apex:actionFunction name="AddOrDelete" action="{!addElement}" reRender="message,hello">
     <apex:param value="" name="fieldName" />
  </apex:actionFunction>
     </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and the controller code is

```
public class sampleCon {
public List<Wrapper> wrap1{get;set;}
public Integer size{get;set;}

public sampleCon(){
wrap1=new List<Wrapper>();
wrap1.add(new wrapper(0));
 size=wrap1.size();

}

public PageReference addElement(){
size=wrap1.size();


System.debug('Hello ji'+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fieldName')+'size is'+size);
Integer i=Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fieldName'));

if(i == size-1)
{
wrap1.add(new wrapper(size));

size++;
}

return null;

}


    public class wrapper{
    public integer i{get;set;}
    public String x{get;set;}
    public wrapper(Integer p){
i=p;
    }}
    }
```

what i am trying is the last row button label should be Add and other button label should be Delete when i press add button a new row is added and the label should be changed acordingly for this i am adding row but it is not working as expected

initial page screenshot is 
[image]
when i press add button screen look like this.
[image]
when i again press the Add button screen is looking like first screenshot.i was expecting that one more row will be added when i click add button in above screenshot.can any one please tell why only one row is showing when i click add button in second screen shot and how to correct it that when i again click on add button on above screen one more row will be added instead of showing initial screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a list at below post:

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Add-Row-functionality-in-VisualForce/m-p/358921

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya i think i am also doing the same as u can see on clicking add i am adding an element to list and increasing the size with one but why instead of increasing it it is again setting the size to 1 please help me i am very badly stuck in this issue please please help.please see the code and give correction

Comment: sincerely ur help will be highly appreciable

Comment: I think this is how your approach should be. You need to pass {!item.i} as a parameter to addElement in the controller which you are not doing. once you pass the parameter, you should increment it and create list using the parameter instead of size. I.e. Wrap1.add(new wrapper(i)) and then finally set size = wrap1.size().